# Fixing Earth Engine client library loading failure

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

[image]

The problem is I can not enter into google earth engine editor and I can not use any dataset and bring any shapefiles or other data formats.

Comment: Please always include error messages as formatted text and not only within a picture.

Comment: Click in "CONTINUE TO EARTH ENGINE" or reload current page (Ctrl+R) in your browser.